# Taylor: $f'(x) - f'(y) \leq C (x-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

Let $f \in C^2([a,b])$. How can I show that there has to exist a $C>0$ such that for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ we have $f'(x) - f'(y) \leq C(x-y)$ using Taylor-expansion (and the Lagrange-formula)?

Comment: You need some absolute values in that.

Comment: You may add as many absolute values as you need to make this question as senseful as possible.

Comment: using Taylor-expansion need $f\in C^\infty$

Comment: No worries, let $f$ be C-infinity.

Comment: Let $C= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f''(x)|$ and upper bound the Taylor remainder, assuming that $x<y$.